# How to list key-value associative array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

Assume that we have an array:

```
$aa = array('student1'=>array(1,2,3),'student2'=>array(3,2,4),'student3'=>array(4,3,5));
```

I want to have an HTML output like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>student1
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>student2
        <ul>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>student3
        <ul>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But all I could do is

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <ul>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <ul>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In other words, I was not able to print keys for each inner array. How to do that?

I have coded something like that:

```
echo '<ul>';

foreach($aa as $a)
{
    echo '<li>' . /*Here it should be written the current student name*/ '<ul>';

    foreach($a as $b)
    {
        echo '<li>' . $b . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></li>';

}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried? I'm assuming you did a foreach as a test, but you didn't post any code so I'm just guessing. And second, you can do `foreach($array as $key=>$value)` which will set `$key` to the key. And lastly, here is the manual for foreach: http://www.php.net/foreach. It shows how to use the loop to get key/value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ul>
<?php
  foreach ($aa as $name => $values) {
    echo "<li>$name\n";
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach ($values as $value) {
      echo "<li>$value</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
    echo "</li>\n";
  }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is effectively what the OP is asking. If you want to learn to make it so that an infinite amount of nesting can occur, you're going to need to learn about [Recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

Answer (score 0):

Print the array like this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

This way you look at the internal structure of the array.

Then you can list it like this:

```
$a = array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "seventeen" => 17
);

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    echo "\$a[$k] => $v.\n";
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks so much. This is not the thing I am looking for. I want to learn controlling foreach structure.